# Godot Audio Reference cannot be found

Tags: c#, godot4

I have been learning Godot 4 with C# and I came across a problem related to getting a reference to a node in a script.

```
public override void _Ready()
    {
        AudioStreamPlayer2D audio = GetNode<AudioStreamPlayer2D>("AudioPlayerThingy");
        audio.Stream = GD.Load<AudioStream>("res://DRUMS.wav");
        audio.Play();
    }
```

It keeps saying that the `AudioStreamPlayer2D` Node, "AudioPlayerThingy," is not found relative to its sibling, a sprite2d renderer. I have made sure that I have not made any typos, and the tutorial I am following is from Godot 3 so I dont know if it is outdated for this question. What do I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expressions:

```
GetNode<AudioStreamPlayer2D>("AudioPlayerThingy")
```

Would have Godot try to retrieve a *child* `AudioStreamPlayer2D` that has a `name` set to `"AudioPlayerThingy"`.

---

However, you say:

> It keeps saying that the `AudioStreamPlayer2D` Node, "AudioPlayerThingy," is not found relative to its sibling, a sprite2d renderer.

If you want a sibling, you would do this:

```
GetNode<AudioStreamPlayer2D>("../AudioPlayerThingy")
```

This expression would have Godot try to retrieve a *sibling* `AudioStreamPlayer2D` that has a `name` set to `"AudioPlayerThingy"`.

I'll point out that if there is any chance that you would move those `Node`s around in the scene tree in the future, that would break. Usually we assume that when we move a `Node` in the scene tree, we move it with its children. However, here you would have a `Node` depending on a sibling, which is a non-obvious dependency.

---

Consider setting the `Node` to have a unique name in the scene (the option is in the context menu of the `Node` in the scene dock). With that enabled, you could do use this:

```
GetNode<AudioStreamPlayer2D>("%AudioPlayerThingy")
```

This expression would have Godot try to retrieve a `AudioStreamPlayer2D` that has been set to have a unique name in the scene, and that `name` is set to `"AudioPlayerThingy"`.

---

For people coming from Unity:

Godot does not have a scene/prefab distinction. Here when I say "unique name in the scene" it refers to the scene being edited, which might be instanced multiple times, and each one would have an instance of the `Node` that has an unique name, all having the same name... The name is unique within the instance.

*Also "SpriteRenderer" is not a thing in Godot.*

Comment: Thank you, perfect answer. It also helped me find what I did wrong compared to the tutorial. I was supposed to attach the script to the parent Node, but I accidentally attached it to sprite2D child node.